# Django Migrate With Specific Database And Models

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, migrate

I was tried to create a multiple database and i did it. i wrote the code on setting.py like this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'baseDB', 
        'USER': 'admin', 
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '1234',
    },
    'android': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'androidDB', 
        'USER': 'admin', 
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '1234',
    },
    'ios': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'iosDB', 
        'USER': 'admin', 
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '1234',
    }       
}
```

And i was already create a two models.py like :

```
class AndroidModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default=False)
    version = models.CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'android_label'

class IosModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default=False)
    version = models.CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ios_label'
```

And than i created a routes with the name file is dbrouters and the class is MyDBRouter, and the code is like :

```
from api.models import AndroidModel, IosModel

class MyDBRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'android_label':
            return 'android'

        if UserJembatani._meta.app_label == 'ios':
            return 'ios'

        else:
            return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'android_label':
            return 'android'

        if UserJembatani._meta.app_label == 'ios_label':
            return 'ios'

        else:
            return 'default'

        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'android_label' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'android_label':
           return True

        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'ios_label' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'ios_label':
           return True

        else:
            return 'default'           
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if not UserJembatani._meta.app_label == 'android_label':
            return'android' == db

        if not UserJembatani._meta.app_label == 'ios_label':
            return'ios' == db

        else:
            return 'default' == db

        return None
```

And also i put the the DATABASE_ROUTERS in setting.py :

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('app_mobile.dbrouters.MyDBRouter',)
```

After that i trued to migrate it using command line :

```
python manage.py migrate --database=android
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate --database=android
```

But the problem. when i tried to execute that command, the both of them models always created to the both database. the goal is, i want the model android just create as a table in android database and for the ios models also like the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that (for more info see https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelmultidatabases.html)

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if db == 'ios':            
            if app_label in ['auth','admin','ios']:
                return True            
            elif app_label=='android':                
                return False
        elif db == 'android':
            if app_label in ['auth','admin','android']:
                return True            
            elif app_label=='ios':                
                return False    
        return None
```

Comment: Sorry for late replay, for the condition app_label, you give me an example to put the db name on list of app_label. i mean, that's app_label or db name ?

Comment: because i already tried like the example from you and still didn't work when i run ```python manage.py migrate --database=android```